# Optional many-to-one/References results in foreign key violations on insert

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I currently have the following relationship: `ProductUom -> ProductImage`

They both have the same primary keys:  `PROD_ID` and `UOM_TYPE`

I have them mapped like this:

```
public ProductUomMap()
{
    Table("PROD_UOM");

    CompositeId()
        .KeyReference(x => x.Product, "PROD_ID")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.UomType, "UOM_TYPE");

    References(x => x.Image)
        .Columns(new string[] { "PROD_ID", "UOM_TYPE" })
        .Not.Update()
        .Not.Insert()
        .NotFound.Ignore()
        .Cascade.All();
}

public ProductImageMap()
{
    Table("PROD_UOM_IMAGE");

    CompositeId()
        .KeyReference(x => x.ProductUom, new string[] {"PROD_ID", "UOM_TYPE"});

    Map(x => x.Image, "PROD_IMAGE").Length(2147483647);
}
```

Whenever I create a `ProductUom` object that has a `ProductImage` it tries to insert the `ProductImage` first which results in a **foreign key violation**.  I swear this was working at one time with the mapping that I have but it doesn't now.

I need the `ProductImage` to be a `Reference` (many-to-one) because the relationship here is optional and I want to be able to lazy load product images.  The inserts do work correctly if I use a `HasOne` (one-to-one) mapping but the I cannot lazy load when I do this and querying a `ProductUom` seems to cause issues.

#### Is there something that I'm missing here?  How can this mapping be modified to get what I want?

Answer (score 0):

can you use LazyLoaded Properties? Then you could use something like this

```
Join("PROD_UOM_IMAGE", join =>
{
    join.KeyColumn("PROD_ID", "UOM_TYPE");
    join.Optional();
    join.Map(x => x.Image, "PROD_IMAGE").Length(2147483647).LazyLoad();
}
```

another option is:

```
Id().GeneratedBy.Foreign(x => x.ProductUom);
```

can't test it here though, i'm writing on Mobile

Comment: The join mapping generates the following error when building the session factory: `Foreign key (FK1905F860C2BA1584:PROD_UOM_IMAGE [UOM_TYPE])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (PROD_UOM [PROD_ID, UOM_TYPE])`

Comment: The Id.GeneratedBy.Foreign mapping generates the following error when building the session factory: `FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail. ` Inner exception: `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.`

Comment: are there any overloads for KeyColumn()?

Comment: There is indeed an overload that supports multiple columns `.KeyColumn("PROD_ID", "UOM_TYPE")`.  The insert of the `ProductUom` and `Image` works with the join but the lazy loading does not.  The byte array is null whenever I access it from my product.  If I turn the lazy loading off for that property in the `Join` it works but the image is not lazy loaded.

Comment: Lazy Loading Properties can only be used on entities which can be proxied, maybe something prevents NH to build a Proxy for `ProductUom`,e.g. lazy=false or non virtual properties